# Jacoco fails only on my system with strange error about StringUtils

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Jacoco is giving me this error when trying to test my web service (I get it with any maven goal that includes the test phase):

```
$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Web Service 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to C:\git\myproject\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\git\myproject\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\git\myproject\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:report (post-unit-test) @ myproject ---
[WARNING] Error initializing: org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.DefaultVelocityComponent@1796b2d4
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.initialize(ResourceManagerImpl.java:165)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeResourceManager(RuntimeInstance.java:594)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:241)
        at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.DefaultVelocityComponent.initialize(DefaultVelocityComponent.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.initialize(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.activate(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:207)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Pending.activate(BeanScheduler.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:185)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.152 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-06T09:19:16-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/266M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:report (post-unit-test) on project myproject: Execution post-unit-test of goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:report failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:report: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/0.7.4.201502262128/jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.4.201502262128.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.6/plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2.1/file-management-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-api-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.1/maven-reporting-impl-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.1.2/doxia-core-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1/xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.1.2/doxia-site-renderer-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.1.2/doxia-decoration-model-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.1.2/doxia-module-xhtml-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.1.2/doxia-module-fml-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/commons-validator-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commons-digester-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.4.201502262128-runtime.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.core-0.7.4.201502262128.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.1/asm-debug-all-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/t1572/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.4.201502262128/org.jacoco.report-0.7.4.201502262128.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Just to be clear, I am not using StringUtils anywhere in my code, not even in my test code. My project builds and runs fine without it, if tests are skipped.

I've googled maven issues, jacoco issues, surefire issues, and tried all solutions I came across.

Here is what I tried:

- Clean build, also deleting the whole target directory manually
- Adding several different dependencies containing StringUtils to the pom (including the original commons-lang-2.6.jar and the new commons-lang3 library)
- Deleting my .m2/repository/org/apache/maven directory to redownload all repository libraries
- Comparing with my other projects that use similar test cases to find any possible difference that might cause this
- Using different versions of surefire, failsafe, and surefire-report plugins
- Adding `<skipTests>true</skipTests>` to both surefire and failsafe plugin configurations in the pom (some similar issues I read happened because test cases were being run twice)
- Excluding various output directories using `<exclude>` tag in jacoco plugin configuration
- Altering the source and target JDK versions in the maven compiler plugin configuration
- Inserting the StringUtils.class directly into the jacoco pom in the appropriate directory matching the missing class name and package
- Using different versions of the jacoco plugin
- Installing and using a different version of Maven (tried both 3.1.1 and 3.3.9)
- Switching to cobertura (I get a very similar error that differs only in the class it says is missing - org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils, rather than StringUtils)

I've been pulling my hair out over this for a whole day. I was able to have someone else test it and it worked fine on their system. I then copied their target directory onto my machine and was able to execute Sonar code analysis against the successful build results (jacoco.exec and the checked in code).

**My question is, what is messed up on my system that is causing this?**

I am running Windows 7 64-bit on a HP EliteDesk. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproject.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Web Service</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.4.201502262128</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>internal-repository</id>
            <name>Nexus</name>
            <url>http://repo.example.com/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.net.httpserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>http</artifactId>
            <version>20070405</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    <build>
    <finalName>webservice</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
              <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/static/**</exclude>
              </excludes>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>post-unit-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <dataFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <tomcatLoggingFile>tomcat.log</tomcatLoggingFile>
            <serverxml>${project.basedir}/target/tomcat/conf/web.xml</serverxml>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My test cases aren't anything special, they basically just send a sample POST request to each of the endpoints and verify that a result comes back.

Here is an example test case:

```
private CustomResponse executePostRequest()
{
    MyPojo data = new MyPojo();
    data.setId(0);
    data.setRequestType("sometype");
    data.setSomeField("value");
    data.setSomeOtherField(5);
    return target.path(endpoint).request().post(Entity.json(data), CustomResponse.class);
}

@Test
public void testEndpoint()
{
    CustomResponse response = executePostRequest();
    assertTrue( response.getCode() == 200 );
}
```

I'll be happy to post any other settings or whatever you might want to know about my system.

UPDATE: I just found out about [jHades](http://jhades.github.io/) which is a tool to help you identify conflicting Jar resources when you run into jar-hell scenarios like this. I haven't tried it yet, but I plan to and will update the results here if it produces anything.

Comment: could you post a section where `StringUtils` is used in your code? the one from `org.apache.commons.lang`

Comment: I am not using it at all. Sorry forgot to mention that detail. That's why it's such a baffling error. I didn't even have it pulled in as a dependency before. If I run a build with the tests skipped, it all builds fine.

Comment: `org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.DefaultVelocityComponent`  also doesn't seem to be making use of it either. there seems to be some info missing, could you share the entire stacktrace and logs alongwith the commands used to executed maven lifecycles above

Comment: Sure I will add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- go to `m2\repository\org\jacoco\jacoco-maven-plugin\0.7.4.201502262128`
- add this dependency in `jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.4.201502262128.pom`:

  ```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow and see if it fixes the issue. If it does I will be thrilled.

Comment: I am very certain it will solve the issue. I had this error few times. Each time I searched the relevant .pom file and added common lang dependency, version 2.6 ( version 2.4 doesn't work properly)

Comment: Yep that did it - thank you very much! Such a relief to have this working.